# Getting the create table command used in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I get the create table command which is used to create a table in oracle 11g so that I can copy the command and run it in another database? Please help.

Comment: Do you have PLSQL Developer? Which tools do you have to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE')
from dual;
```

Comment: This query worked. you saved me from a 4 hour search.

Answer (score 1):

Try to spool the output of the below query,

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_TABLES u;
```

Like,

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
set feedback off
set echo off 

spool schema.sql 

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_TABLES u WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your_table>';

spool off;
```

Reference: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below Query

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','YOUR_TABLE_NAME','YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME') from dual;
```

if you use `SQL Developer`, select the table name , and `right click` to choose `Open Declaration` and then Click `SQL` tab on the window that opens!

[image]

Comment: nice info to add to this question